# Erro #1064 no CREATE PROCEDURE - PhpMyAdmin SQL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Mensagem do PhpMyAdmin:

```
Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação
1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a '@NumeroSerie INT(11),
        @Velocidade TINYINT(4),
        @Direcao SMALLINT(6),
        @Latit' na linha 2
```

Código que está com erro:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SpRegistraMsgPosicionamento(
    @NumeroSerie INT(11),
    @Velocidade TINYINT(4),
    @Direcao SMALLINT(6),
    @Latitude DECIMAL(8,4),
    @Longitude DECIMAL(8,4)
)
AS BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO posicionamento(EquipamentoId, Velocidade, Direcao, Latitude, Longitude) 
    VALUES (@NumeroSerie, @Velocidade, @Direcao, @Latitude, @Longitude)
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de bater a cabeça com isso percebi que faltou colocar o `IN`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `SpRegistraMsgPosicionamento`(
    IN `@NumeroSerie` INT, 
    IN `@Velocidade` TINYINT, 
    IN `@Direcao` SMALLINT, 
    IN `@Latitude` DECIMAL(8,4), 
    IN `@Longitude` DECIMAL(8,4)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja se resolve (tirei [daqui](https://www.hostinger.com.br/como/1064-o-que-fazer-se-ha-um-erro-na-sua-sintaxe-sql#gref)):

> O erro 1064 ocorre devido à incompatibilidade da versão do MySQL.
>   Diferentes versões possuem diferentes palavras reservadas, que, se
>   forem usadas por uma versão anterior, provocam o erro.
>
> A solução mais simples e eficaz para isso é a seguinte: ao usar
>   phpMyadmin (acessível a partir do seu Painel de controle), selecione o
>   **"modo de compatibilidade"** e selecione a versão do banco de dados no
>   menu. É isso aí! Você não deve receber o mesmo erro novamente.